# How fill form of an existing PDF and then add it to a new PDF using itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using the following code

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
form.setField("name", "John");
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
stamper.close();
reader.close();
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest2));
document.open();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
//Loading the filled form again as a file
PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(dest);
PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader2, 1);
document.newPage();
cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
document.newPage();
document.add(new Paragraph("my timestamp"));
document.close();
```

Here i am loading the filled file again to add to the new pdf file, how to add the filled pdf to a new pdf from memory without loading as a file again.

Comment: Not sure why this question was down-voted. There was code. The problem was adequately described. Granted, the answer was trivial, but that doesn't make this a bad question, because what is trivial to the experienced developer, might not be trivial to every developer. If you down-vote please add a comment with a link to the [I down-voted because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/) web site. I up-voted the question to undo the down-vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to add the filled pdf to a new pdf from memory without loading as a file again.

In

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
```

replace the `FileOutputStream` by a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instance.

Then in

```
PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(dest);
```

use the `PdfReader` constructor accepting a byte array and feed it the byte array from the `ByteArrayOutputStream` instance.